# How to show up my VOIP app in Contacts app dialer

Tags: ios, iphone, ios11, voip

I am currently working on one VOIP app. I want to show up my app in Contacts app's dialer(Go to contacts app -> click on call button from 4 rounded buttons, the dialer will open) as like other VOIP apps.

[image]

See this image, it list different apps like Hangout, WhatsApp, Viber etc.

What settings or what extra programming I required to do to show my VOIP app in this list. Is there any specific extension for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here i got the solution and its working awesome for me.

```
    let configuration = CXProviderConfiguration(localizedName: "CallKit Quickstart")
    configuration.maximumCallGroups = 1
    configuration.maximumCallsPerCallGroup = 1
    configuration.supportedHandleTypes = [.phoneNumber]

    if let callKitIcon = UIImage(named: "iconMask80") {
        configuration.iconTemplateImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(callKitIcon)
    }

    callKitProvider = CXProvider(configuration: configuration)
```

See the above code, the main eye catching line is

```
    configuration.supportedHandleTypes = [.phoneNumber]
```

If you pass the `.phoneNumber` here, your app will be shown from contacts app considering that you are supporting call from phone number. Similarly if you support email address, then pass it too. This will solve your issue.

Comment: when tap on the phone number it launch my app , in which method i can get the tapped contact

Comment: @RaviOjha Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Sassan Sorry for the late reply . 
On click on the number it call native method (continue userActivity) in appdelegate class. for reference please check it 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623072-application